# Primeros pasos con JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy comenzando con el mundo Java, estoy con conocimientos basicos y quiero comenzar con JavaFX para el desarrollo de aplicaciones de escritorio. Vengo de programar con Visual FoxPro 9.0 asi que mis preguntas para los expertor en JavaFX son:

1. Es JavaFx una buena alternativa a Fox, me refiero al diseño de aplicaciones de escritorio, manejador de reportes, etc.?
2. Existe algun sitio web o documentacion que pueda consultar para comenzar con el estudio?

Answer (score 6):

Te puedo hablar de mi no tan larga experiencia con JavaFX. Después de aprender Swing, en mis inicios, me llamó la atención JavaFX y lo aprendí. Mi primera impresión fue que es un toolkit muy potente, bastante customizable y con muchos widgets o controles. Por ejemplo, puedes mostrar gráficos sin necesidad de librerías, pie charts, bar charts, etc. En los TableView puedes fácilmente personalizar el renderizado para poner imágenes en celdas, etc.

Una de las características que más me gustó fue la posibilidad de usar CSS directamente sobre los controles, lo que me permitió hacer unas UIs muy bonitas, me recordó a GTK.

Si bien ha llegado un poco tarde (como WPF de Microsoft), es una realmente buena alternativa a Swing y a otros toolkits. Si tienes algo de experiencia en Java, la curva de aprendizaje será muy corta.

Sobre recursos, puedes seguir [este tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/) en español, trata del desarrollo de una agenda.

Comment: Gracias @Mitsu voy a seguir el tutorial y espero aprender bastante porque me llama mucho la atención a tal punto de que quiero desarrollar algunas aplicaciones con JavaFX.